# Checkbox in web application automation (UIPath)

Tags: web, checkbox, uipath

I want to automate a process in web application using UIPath. There is a check box which need to be checked everytime I want to generate report. I was trying to automate using "click" in UI automation. There is no issue on the first process.
However, the check box doesn't reset to "uncheck" after the first process is done. 
So the next time I run the process again, the check box get clicked again into "uncheck" condition.

I want to create an automation to check if the check box state is "checked" or "uncheck". If the state is "checked", then I want to skip the click check box process.

What is the ideal way to do this? I imagine using workflow flow decision. But if anybody can elaborate which function I need touse. It would be a great help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just use the UiPath activity **Check**. You can find it in Ui Automation > Element > Control. Look for the property **Action** and in your case choose check (default). This won't check the checkbox if its already checked.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Get Attribute activity and you'll need to identify the attribute name for the checkbox that you are looking to extract. You can then assign it's value to a variable(probably a string) and check the value and proceed accordingly. In my test case it was the "text" attribute I needed to use which brought back a value of either checked or unchecked.